# dialogue environment beginning with \direct fails

Tags: errors

I am using the `dialogue` environment, and I want to start a dialogue with a setting, using the `\direct` command. However, the following code does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dialogue}

\begin{document}

\begin{dialogue}
  \direct{This is a setting.}

  \speak{John Doe} I am speaking.
\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

....

l.10 \speak{John Doe}
                         I am speaking.
```

This doesn't happen when I start with `\speak`. What should I do to get around this apparent bug in the package?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize that the MWE needed to also include the `\documentclass` and included packages, etc. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I'm just wondering whether there exist other packages doing this thing, since this one seems rather badly written...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems to be a bug in `dialogue`.  I'd suggest this quick-and-dirty fix (which I hope doesn't break anything...):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\appto{\PreDialogue}{\global\@newlistfalse}
\makeatother
```

Also, I guess `\direct` should start with a `\par` or maybe even `\par\medskip` or something.  I'd definitely consider hacking this package a bit.

Comment: If you want inline stage directions, however, I don't think a `\par` at the beginning of every `\direct` would work.

Comment: +1.  Seems it's been a long time since I actually *read* some play;)...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `dialogue` environment can't start with a `\direct{}` command due to the `list` structure which creates an orphan `\item`. Taking it out from the `dialogue` environment solves the error. Putting a `\speak` before works too. Also in the manual (14 years old!) it's stated that `\direct{}` command has a different meaning which might be this detail.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dialogue}

\begin{document}

\direct{This is a setting.}
\begin{dialogue}
\speak{Play-Doh} I said speak!
\speak{John Doe} I am speaking.
\end{dialogue}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will work for the given scenario, but it is unfortunate that it gives a different level of indentation than the other `\direct`s.